# Umbraco Embed URL not working throws an error ould not embed media - please ensure the URL is valid

Tags: razor, umbraco, umbraco7

been trying to use the Umbraco Embed content type but the error says
 **Could not embed media - please ensure the URL is valid.**

i have tried with https://vimeo.com/269996086 , https://youtu.be/JGwWNGJdvx8 all these URL but none of them working any idea about this ? [image]

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue but I know the validation is based on `/config/embeddedmedia.config`, could you check if youtube and vimeo are present in that file? For more info, check out: https://our.umbraco.com/documentation/extending/Embedded-Media-Provider/

Comment: Hey Gayathri, what version of Umbraco are you running?

Comment: @Mark youtube and vimeo is there <!-- Youtube Settings -->
  <provider name="Youtube" type="Umbraco.Web.Media.EmbedProviders.OEmbedVideo, umbraco">
    <urlShemeRegex><![CDATA[youtu(?:\.be|be\.com)/(?:(.*)v(/|=)|(.*/)?)([a-zA-Z0-9-_]+)]]></urlShemeRegex>
    <apiEndpoint><![CDATA[https://www.youtube.com/oembed]]></apiEndpoint>
    <requestParams type="Umbraco.Web.Media.EmbedProviders.Settings.Dictionary, umbraco">
      <param name="iframe">1</param>
      <param name="format">xml</param>
      <param name="scheme">https</param>
    </requestParams>
  </provider>

Comment: hi @Pheonyx i am using 7.10

Comment: @GayathriMohan Were you ever able to find a solution for this? 
I just ran into this and I'm running Umbraco 7.12.3